# List with struct pointer

Tags: c

I have the following code but the result is null for all components of the structure:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct _TransactionType
{
    char    field1[20];
    char    field2[20]; 
}TransactionType;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    int numreg = 0;
    char  temp[12];
    TransactionType *dbTransaction;

    dbTransaction = (TransactionType*) calloc(10,sizeof(TransactionType));


    for(i=0; i<5;i++)
    {
        memset(temp,0,sizeof(temp));        
        sprintf(temp,"%d",i);
        strcpy(dbTransaction->field1, temp);
        dbTransaction->field1[strlen(dbTransaction->field1)] = '\0';
        strcpy(dbTransaction->field2, temp);
        dbTransaction->field2[strlen(dbTransaction->field2)] = '\0';
        numreg++;
        dbTransaction++;    
    }

    printf("reg = %d\n", numreg);

    for (i=0; i<numreg;i++)
    {
        printf("dbTransaction->field1 = %s\n",(dbTransaction + i)->field1);
        printf("dbTransaction->field2 = %s\n",(dbTransaction + i)->field2);

    }


    return 0;
}
```

i need to recover the structure values.
Please any kind of help will be appreciate
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: What's the point of setting the terminators explicitely? They are already there.

Comment: ...and if they are not, `strlen` won't help.

Comment: `dbTransaction++;` feel wrong.

Comment: `dbTransaction++` - you are loosing the initial pointer.

Comment: You must work with a temporary variable, by the time you get to the `printf` the pointer is out of range of memory allocated.

Comment: @WeatherVane not exactly out of range, out of valid occurrences.

Comment: @SouravGhosh indeed, used 5 out of 10.

Answer (score 1):

You should add error checking and casting of `calloc` values is discouraged, but the reason your code doesn't work is that you advance `dbTransaction` pointer in your loop, but never rewind it. The prints you're making are actually of elements 5-9 of the array while you fill elements 0-4.

See the corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct _TransactionType
{
    char    field1[20];
    char    field2[20];
}TransactionType;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    int numreg = 0;
    char  temp[12];
    TransactionType *dbTransaction;
    TransactionType *dbTransactionRoot;

    dbTransaction = (TransactionType*) calloc(10,sizeof(TransactionType));
    dbTransactionRoot = dbTransaction;


    for(i=0; i<5;i++)
    {
        memset(temp,0,sizeof(temp));
        sprintf(temp,"%d",i);
        strcpy(dbTransaction->field1, temp);
        dbTransaction->field1[strlen(dbTransaction->field1)] = '\0';
        strcpy(dbTransaction->field2, temp);
        dbTransaction->field2[strlen(dbTransaction->field2)] = '\0';
        numreg++;
        dbTransaction++;
    }

    printf("reg = %d\n", numreg);

    for (i=0; i<numreg;i++)
    {
        printf("dbTransaction->field1 = %s\n",(dbTransactionRoot + i)->field1);
        printf("dbTransaction->field2 = %s\n",(dbTransactionRoot + i)->field2);

    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is True; Thanks very much

Comment: You should also consider accessing the pointer as array, with the bracket notation instead of incrementing it, it would allow you to eliminate the helper pointer